# CSS to align 3 layout elements for a chat interface

Tags: html, css, layout

[image: chat layout]

I am trying to build a chat interface in a browser window, I cannot get the CSS right, I tried for around 10 hours.

Cell #1 and #3 are fixed

**Edit:** #3 should be a fixed height too e.g 80px; the rest of the window height will be used by the #2.

Cell #2 (the large one) in the middle will contain the chat lines and any window resize should put the scrollbar on that one, not on the full window.
Cell #2 should also align the content at the bottom, so that only 1-2 lines will **not** be far away on the top of the window.

I was able to do it near-perfect using this CSS on cell #2:

```
flex-direction:column;
flex-flow: row wrap;
align-content:flex-end;
```

But it would not place scroll-bars on that cell, only IE does it.
I am thinking there must be a cleaner way, because my CSS looks ugly, I even tried with tables.

[Here is what I have now](http://codepen.io/adrianTNT/pen/meLCk), I guess it is hard to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is a bit oldschool, but does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/runPK/

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="log"></div>
    <div id="composer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: inherit;
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}
#primary {
    margin-left: 200px;
    height: inherit;
}
#log {
    height: 80%;
    background-color: silver;
    overflow: auto;
}
#composer {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: darkgray;
}
```

**Version 2:**
For a fixed height of the composer element, use this CSS for `#log` and `#composer`

```
#log {
    height: calc(100% - 150px);
    background-color: silver;
    overflow: auto;
}
#composer {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: darkgray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/runPK/1/

Comment: I forgot to mention it but the one at bottom should have a fixed height rather than a percent, then the rest of the window height is used by the large one above it.

Comment: @adrianTNT please have a look at the bottom of the answer. http://jsfiddle.net/runPK/1/

Comment: That seems to do it. Wow `height: calc(100% - 150px);` I was not aware of this, I needed it so many times. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome. yes `calc()` is awesome, i also was celebrating when i found it ;)

Comment: Do you know a good way to make content in that main cell align at the bottom ? (like in my image)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56658/discussion-between-adriantnt-and-nico-o).

Comment: @adrianTNT i really think this is one of the things javascript will need to take care of. You asked for layout and this should be done by now. Nobody is going to code the whole thing for you. Keep trying or open a new question regarding this topic.

Comment: Sure Nico, I didn't meant to be picky, `flex-end` does that very well but removes scrollbar from main window. I will try with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Use floats to get things laid out correctly. Percentage heights/widths for elements that change on resize. Also a bit of javascript to keep the text at the bottom of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/KH45Y/

HTML:

```
<body>  
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="top">Top
            <div id="empty"></div>
            <div id="chatContent"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            Bottom<br/>
            <textarea id="message">Heres some default texxt.</textarea><br/>
            <button id="clickMe">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    height:500px;
}
#left{
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
#right{
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    float:right;
}
#top{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background-color:red;
    height:80%;
}
#bottom{
    height:20%;
    background-color:green;
    float:bottom;
}
#chatContent{
    width:100%;
};
#empty{
    width:100%;
};
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(event){
        $('#chatContent').append($('#message').val()+"<br>");
        $('#empty').height($('#top').height()-$('#chatContent').height());
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't understand how the text is appended at the bottom, what does that JS do ? It is jQuery ?

Comment: The #empty div keeps the #chatContent pushed to the bottom. When content is added to the #chatContent div, the #empty div's height is adjusted to #top.height() - #chatContent.height().

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using floats properly.

View this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4ZqzP/1/

Clearfix Info:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc at magna nulla. Curabitur vulputate purus sed ligula suscipit placerat.</div>
    <div class="item3">Bottom Item</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {content: ""; display: table;} 
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;}

.item1,
.item3{
    float: left;
}

.item1{
    width: 20%;
    background-color: magenta;
    height: 600px;
}

.item2{
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: lime;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.item3{
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks remixdesign but these fixed heights on the larger window doesn't do what I needed.